# Attaching a callback to the output element of the Remote IO

Tags: core-audio

I want to capture audio from the microphone of an iOS device and write it to a .caf file.

I'm able to connect a Remote IO audio unit to a multichannel mixer unit (MCMU) and attach a callback to the input of the MCMU. Inside that callback I can successfully write the audio data from the mic to a file using ExtAudioFileAsyncWrite().

I want to simplify things and remove the MCMU from the picture. My thinking is I can simply attach a callback to the output bus of the Remote IO's input scope and inside that callback call ExtAudioFileAsyncWrite().

However when I try this ExtAudioFileAsyncWrite() returns a -50 (paramError).

Is it not possible to attach a callback to the output bus of the input element of the Remote IO?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible. You'll want to use `AudioUnitSetProperty` to set the [`kAudioOutputUnitProperty_SetInputCallback`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioUnit/Reference/AudioUnitPropertiesReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/kAudioOutputUnitProperty_SetInputCallback) property. This callback will function much like a render callback, but will be called whenever the RemoteIO / mic has some new data for you (instead of as a request for data from your program).

Example:

```
AURenderCallbackStruct callbackInfo = {YourInputCallback, NULL};
AudioUnitSetProperty(remoteIO,
                     kAudioOutputUnitProperty_SetInputCallback,
                     kAudioUnitScope_Global,
                     0,
                     &callbackInfo,
                     sizeof(callbackInfo));
```

This will make the RemoteIO / mic call `YourInputCallback` whenever it has a new batch of samples. You can use this callback to call `ExtAudioFileWriteAsync` as you did before. Note that you'll have to call `AudioUnitRender` on the RemoteIO as well, to get the new samples out of it.

Regarding the -50 error, that's not a very helpful error diagnostic. It basically just says "there was an error with one of your parameters". Most likely your `ExtAudioFile` was NULL or not set up properly (in which case, one of the `ExtAudioFile*` functions you used on it earlier would have returned a more helpful error code you can use to diagnose it).

Comment: Thanks for this. I mistyped above: the -50 error is returned when I call AudioUnitRender() inside my callback function.  Shouldn't the AudioUnitElement argument in AudioUnitSetProperty() be 1, instead of 0?

Comment: In the case of Global params, it's always 0 (since the Global scope doesn't even have "elements"). I know it's odd, since it's actually affecting the Input of the RemoteIO, but as far as Core Audio is considered, `kAudioOutputUnitProperty_SetInputCallback` is a Global scope param, not an Input/Output scope param.

Comment: Also, `paramErr` in `AudioUnitRender` almost certainly means your RemoteIO is NULL / not initialized / set up improperly, or your `ioData` AudioBufferList is in the wrong format. In the case of "not set up properly", one of the earlier Core Audio functions would probably have returned an OSStatus telling you more. If it's NULL, well, it's NULL and it shouldn't be (but you knew that :)).